# PHP Inheritance: How to reference a child object from parent?

Tags: php, inheritance, amazon-s3

I am trying to write some code that access images from S3 on AWS using inheritance. I have gotten the code to work in one long file but it gets a bit unwieldy.

I am new to PHP inheritance so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I have a class called `PersonPics` that inherits from `myAWS`. These are referenced in a third file `downloadImages`.

I've traced the error to be related to the `$s3Client` variable.

When I have the code written in the `myAWS` class written as`$this->s3Client->getIterator(...)` I get an error calling member function on null error. If I change it to `$this->$s3Client->getIterator(...)`I get a undefined variable `s3ClientError` despite it being defined in the constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

**myAWS.php**

```
class myAWS{
    private $s3Client;
    private $bucket = 'my-bucket';

    function __construct() {
        $S3Client = S3Client::factory(array( ... )); //credentials inserted
    }

    function getImages($name){

        $img_iter = $this->s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
               'Bucket' => $bucket,
               'Prefix' => $name . '/img',
        ));

        // ... more
        return img_arr;
    }
}
```

**PersonPics.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
require_once __DIR__ . '/myAWS.php';

class PersonPics extends myAWS {
    public $name;

    function __construct($name){
        $this->$name = $name;
    }

    function getImages(){
         $pic_arr = parent::getImages($this->name);
         // more functionality to be added later using $pic_arr
    }
}
```

**downloadImages.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/myAWS.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PersonPics.php';

$name = $_GET["name"];
$aws = new myAWS();
$lookupPerson = new PersonPics($name);
$images = $lookupPerson->getImages();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you are setting a local variable. You mean to be setting the member variable. Change it to:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->s3Client = S3Client::factory(array( ... )); //credentials inserted
}
```

Note the change in case of the 's' in the variable name as well.

Comment: Thanks! that works, wasn't aware of the syntax for it. So to access member variables you declare them as `public /private $var` and then have to access them using `$this->var`?

Comment: That's correct, as far as it goes, but there are other options too. Here's [the relevant page from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your myAWS.php class with below code and let me know if it works for you

```
class myAWS{
    private $s3Client;
    private $bucket = 'my-bucket';

    function __construct() {
        $this->s3Client = S3Client::factory(array( ... )); //credentials inserted
    }

    function getImages($name){

        $img_iter = $this->s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
               'Bucket' => $bucket,
               'Prefix' => $name . '/img',
        ));

        // ... more
        return img_arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you change anything?

Comment: In order to access member variable of a class you have to access that in "$this->variableName" in your case you have declared  private $s3Client so ideally in your case it should be accessed "$this->s3Client" this way